# I Got Stuck in infinite loop in react.js. How to resolve this?

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, use-effect

**I Got Stuck in an infinite loop in react.js. How to resolve this?**

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://react-http-d55a9-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/todo.json")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setUsersList((prev) => [...prev]);           //cause of infinite loop
      });
  }, [usersList]);
```

Comment: Why would you want to run this effect when usersList is changed?

Comment: Because to make sure that whenever userList updated, the data should be fetched from database and should be rendered on screen.

Comment: Why would you have to fetch from the db after userList changes, when you don't really pass the userList in the HTTP request's body or as a param? Anyway the API is going to return the same data.
If you are persisting the userList to db when it changes via some other api, then you should not keep this as an effect. Instead you can make this as a function and call the function, from the `then` part of the POST or PUT api that you use to persist the userList in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having an infinite loop because your `useEffect` array of dependencies has `usersList` on it and at the same time you are updating this variable inside your `useEffect` function. So your `useEffect` runs when the component mounts which updates your `usersList` which makes the `useEffect` run again which again updates your `usersList` which makes it run again and so on...
To fix this, remove `usersList` from the array of dependencies and have an empty array instead: `[]`. If you do this your `useEffect` will run once, when your component mounts.

Comment: But If I will take empty array of dependency, then my useEffect will run only once at the start when I will refresh the page, But after that how this useEffect is going to be called.? Is there any other way to solve by making sure that useEffect should be called whenever usersList changed..

Comment: To call this `useEffect` when `usersList` changes you can't update `usersList` inside it, if you do you get an infinite loop as I explained above.
Could you give some more insight as to why you would want this to run every time `usersLists` gets updated and how exactly you are updating it outside of this `useEffect`?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency list passed to `useEffect` determines when the effect should run again. The infinite loop is happening because this effect causes `usersList` to change, which triggers the effect to run again.

Since this effect doesn't use any other variables, it doesn't need anything in its dependency list:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(...)
  // ...
}, []); // leave this empty, so the effect only runs when the component mounts
```

If your URL depended on a prop or something else, then you want it in the dependency list:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`https://example.com/todo/${props.id}`)
    .then(...)

  // Since the URL depends on the id prop, the effect should re-run if it changes
}, [props.id]);
```

Comment: But there is one problem, If I will take an empty array of dependency, then my useEffect will run only once at the start when I will refresh the page, But after that how this useEffect is going to be called.? Is there any other way to solve by making sure that useEffect should be called whenever users list changed

Comment: The effect is responsible for _setting_ the users list, that's why it calls `setUserList` at the end. It doesn't make sense for the effect to run when `usersList` changes, because that's what causes the infinite loop. (I am assuming that `usersList` and `setUsersList` are a pair returned from useState, if that's not true then you'll need to show the source of your whole component for us to understand what you should do).

Comment: Both are paired. 
What do you mean by saying this - it doesn't make sense for the effect to run when usersList changes. Do you mean that if this usersList updated then this useEffect will also be called again. If that's what are you trying to say then I wanna confirm one thing, is it right that useEffect called only once if we take dependency as empty?

Comment: Yes, an empty dependency array means the effect will only run once, when the component mounts. I recommend reading the [useEffect documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), it will do a better job explaining how everything works than I can do here.

Comment: Ok so now here the two main question arises,                                                               
If i will take here an empty array of dependency then this useEffect will not be called again? But if I want to execute this useEffect every time the userlist changed then how can I do this?                            
And if i will take here empty array of Dependency then this will not going to fetch the data again?

Comment: Please update your question with the full source of your component. It's hard to answer your question without having a better understanding of what your component is doing.

Answer (score 0):

According to question asked, you want the userList to be watched everytime it updates. What we can do is define one more state variable as mentioned in the code as isFetched or if you are using redux you can put that over there, because if we just watch the userList variable then it caughts up in infinite loop as setting the userList is happening in useEffect itself. With the help of isFetched, we can manage when to call the api and whenever the flag is false it calls the api.

Right now in the code i have put one more state variable as setCount, as i didn't know how many times you want to call your api. So you can put your condition there and stop the call when your condition satisfies.

```js
function App() {
  const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);
  const [isFetched, setIsFetched] = useState(false);
  const [, setCount] = useState(3);

  const callApiPending = useCallback(()=>{
    fetch("https://react-http-d55a9-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/todo.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      setUserList((prev) => [...prev, ...json]);
      setCount((cnt) => {
        if(cnt - 1 === 0){
          setIsFetched(true);
        }
        return cnt - 1;
      });
      
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetched) {
      callApiPending();
    }
  }, [isFetched, userList, callApiPending]);

  return <div>Executing....</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ran fetch if usersList changes. Even if userList content is the same as previous content, javascript interpret as it changed. Try this one.

```
[1,2,3] == [1,2,3]
```

may return false. You can use a flag which is used to check whether or not to get data instead of using array.